# Set directory tree to belong to fixed group

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, user-groups

I have a directory tree under `/mnt/data` where I would like to keep data. I would ike my user:

- `guest` to have read access
- `student` to have read and write access
- `me` to also have read and write access

I would like to be able to do this without assigning both `student` and `me` to the same primary group.

The issue that confuses me most is that if `me` creates a file in that directoy, it will be owned by `me:me`, and neither `student:student` or `student:wheel` wil not be able to edit it... So it seems the only way around this is to put `me` and `student` in the same group - which I do not want.

What can I do? Is there any way to tell my system that if `me` modifies anything in that directory it should be done as `me:wheel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use setgid permissions

```
chgrp  wheel /mnt/data   
chmod g+s /mnt/data
```

After setting this all files created in the directory will be owned by the group of the current directory.

You may create a new group "data" and put student and you in that group

Then chgrp the directory to "data"

and then set setgid bit.